# Value# error when using averageIFs in Excel

Tags: excel, average

I am getting the following error VALUE# when I try to use the AVERAGEIFS function on the following data:

[image]

Below is my AVERAGEIFS function:

```
  =AVERAGEIFS(D2:H9,A:C,"*Male*",A:C,"*Artist*")
```

Could you please advise on why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVERAGEIFS() requires that all the ranges must be the same size and shape. You are comparing three whole columns to a range 5 columns wide and 8 rows high.

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" Male "," " & B2:B9 & " "))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Artist",C2:C9))*D2:H9)/SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" Male "," " & B2:B9 & " "))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Artist",C2:C9))*(D2:H9>0))
```

Note the spaces around `" Male "` other wise it will pick up the `male` in `Female`.

[image]

Comment: Hello thank you for your help :) however this is not what I mean. I mean the average of score so the answer should actually be 3+2+3+1+3+6+8+1+4+7+4+5+4 divided by 13 which would 3.9 :)? is there a way to do this

Comment: @user3062448 see edit.  please mark as correct if this works for you by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Also, Next time please include as much information in the original question, which should include expected output.